# How to understand fall off the menu?

Tags: idioms

It's never been cheaper, but home cooking has fallen off the menu. What's "fall off the menu" here?

Comment: I think that tries to imply that no one is cooking at home nowadays.

Comment: It's as though it were an item that has been removed from a restaurant menu, presumably because few diners ordered it.